# Why the loop "scanf" method dead circle in objective-c lanuguage?

Tags: objective-c, scanf, stdin, fflush

I write a small console program in objective-c. It need to use the scanf method to receive the number.When I enter a character, it will make a mistake.So I try to solve it,but it has entered a cycle of death! See the following code, to help me solve it, thank you very much!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        int num1 = 0;
        NSLog(@"Please input number:");
        while (!scanf("%d", &num1)) {
            fflush(stdin);
            NSLog(@"Input error,just input number:");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `fflush` states:

> The function fflush() forces a write of all buffered data for the given output or update stream via the
>        stream's underlying write function.  The open status of the stream is unaffected.

and you are trying to flush *input*. Try `fpurge`:

> The function fpurge() erases any input or output buffered in the given stream.

Also **do not** write `!scanf(...)`. Check the documentation, this function returns an integer, not a boolean, and the value could be positive or negative (look up the definition of `EOF`). A negative value indicates an error, but the `!` operator will yield `false` and your code would not ask for new input.

If successful `scanf` returns the number of items successfully parsed, check for that.

The documentation for all these functions is available via Xcode or the `man` command.

HTH